# Mathematics Probability Question

Tags: probability

Probability Mass function

$$f(x)= \begin{cases}
c(2/3)^x & x=1,2,3\ldots \\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}.$$

Find $c$

Not sure how to find $c$ here as we are not given anything for $f(x)$.

A hint or help would be very much appreciated.

From the hints given, i tried solving and i did this.

Since the sum of all x's is equaled to 1. I did

$c[((2/3)^1)+((2/3)^2)+((2/3)^3))=1=$
$c[(2/3)+(4/9)+(8/27)]=1$ Now after calculations we get $1.407c=1$ so we get $c=0.71$

Correction:$c[((2/3)^1+(2/3)^2+(2/3)^3+..)]$

We now use the formula Sums= $a/(1-r)$ where a=2/3 and r=2/3

So we get $c[(2/3)/(1-(2/3))]=1 
=c[2]=1 =
c=1/2$

It then asks me to find $P(x>4|x>2)$

Comment: "Find $c$ **such that** ..."... your question is incomplete...

Comment: It just says Find c

Comment: Is this a probability question? Is f(x) a PDF? A CDF?

Comment: @KitterCatter: I imagine it's a probability mass function, for a discrete random variable that takes values on the positive integers, and the sum has to equal $1$.

Comment: @Student54125: You only got $c = 0.71$ because you stopped after three terms.  The $\ldots$ after the $3$ indicates that it goes on forever.  You should use the sum of the geometric series: $a+ar+ar^2+ar^3+\cdots = \frac{a}{1-r}$.

Comment: Thanks Brian i think i got the first part of the question.

Answer (score 2):

Big Hint: If it is a probability mass function, the sum will equal 1.

$$\sum_{x=1}^\infty f(x)=1$$

PS: Also, do recall the Geometric Series.